# How to calculate the price of Neo4j enterprise if i get data from S3

Tags: neo4j

I need to estimate the price of enterprise Neo4j if get data from S3 (100GB) but i don't find any document to reference. Is there anyone know this?

Answer (score 1):

There are two components of the cost. Those of Neo4j per se and then of the virtual machine. The latter will be based on the size of the database which can be computed (approximated) based on the number of nodes, relationships and edges.

https://neo4j.com/hardware-sizing/

You'll have to work with Neo4j or the hosting platform on the cost of their software.